# xdebug_info not running on MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug

I am trying to get Xdebug running on my MAMP Apache server https://xdebug.org/docs/install . I keep on getting this error when running the following command

```
xdebug_info();
```

Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_info() in
```

Here are my configuration in the CORRECT php.ini file

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1   
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

Comment: Get `phpinfo()` and check if Xdebug is mentioned there.

Comment: It is mentioned as a "HTTP_COOKIE"  - "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM"

Comment: That's nothing. If Xdebug extension is correctly installed and enabled, it will have 2 major entries: a brief summary with version at the top and whole Xdebug section with current settings (just like any other extension). If it's not there then Xdebug is NOT installed/enabled. P.S. Try restarting your MAMP (Apache in particular) -- it may still use old php.ini config

Comment: restarted and still its not there. Anywhere else I should look?It says "no-debug-non-zts-20190902" is that ok?

Comment: Here are examples of the Xdebug section in `phpinfo()` output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhRvk.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/afExq.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3d2i.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLjTk.png. The brief summary will be under such table (that is displayed at the top of the output): https://i.stack.imgur.com/HROfW.png

Comment: 1) Post your `phpinfo()` output captured via browser -- the top table part. 2) What config file you have edited? full path plz.

Comment: ok I figured it out I was editing the wrong file!Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

`xdebug_info();` is only available for Xdebug 3. If PHP says it can not find that function, then you're not running Xdebug 3 yet.

Comment: I wondered if this was this issue, as everything else looked fine - I couldn't see anywhere on the xdebug web page about this only applying to newer versions.